# Reading HTTP Response When Request Isn't Fully Sent

Tags: okhttp

If I send a large POST request using OkHttp, but the server responds quickly with an error (e.g. permission denied) I get a

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)( status = 272 )
```

exception.

Command line tools like curl seem to handle this case just fine and are able to return the HTTP Response instead of aborting because the write failed.

Is there a way to configure OkHttp to do the same?